# sine computation with CORDIC results in not precise values

Tags: c, math, numeric, ieee-754, approximation

I am trying to implement the CORDIC algorithm for approximating a sine function in single precision, on architecture with no FPU. I compare the result obtained from my implementation with results obtained from standard C math functions. I tried implementing in two ways: 1) directly using floating-point operations, 2) converting the input to fixed-point and using integer based operations.
I compare the results obtained from sinf(), sin() and sin() cast to float. The comparison is based on comparing the hexadecimal representations of the result with the expected from math functions.

In (1) the implementation uses double types, then the result is cast to float. My calculated values are always off by at least one hexadecimal digit, no matter how many iterations are done with CORDIC.

In (2), initially the input was mapped to a 32 bit integer.  The error was the same as in (1). Only after, increasing the fixed point size to 64 bit (and the number of iterations to 64) the precision improved. But yet, there are ranges of input for which the algorithm is not precise. If I would increase the fixed point size to 128 bit (and the number of iterations to 128), it may be enough to obtain precise values but it is completely unpractical.

The algorithm in (1) is a modified version from the book https://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const double cordic_1K = 0.6072529350088812561694467525049282631123908521500897724;
double *cordic_ctab;

void make_cordic_ctab(ulong na)
{
    double s = 1.0;
    for (ulong k=0; k<na; ++k)
    {
        cordic_ctab[k] = atan(s);
        s *= 0.5;
    }
}


void cordic(int theta, double* s, double* c, int n)
{
    double x, y, z, v;
    double tx, ty, tz;
    double d;

    x = cordic_1K;
    y = 0;
    z = theta;
    v = 1.0;

    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        d = (z >= 0 ? +1 : -1);
        tx = x - d * v * y;
        ty = y + d * v * x;
        tz = z - d * cordic_ctab[k];
        x = tx;
        y = ty;
        z = tz;
        v *= 0.5;
    }
    *c = x;
    *s = y;
}
```

The algorithm in (2) a is modified version found at http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~jhw/cordic/

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define cordic_1K 0x26dd3b6a10d79600
#define CORDIC_NTAB 64

void cordic(long theta, long *s, long *c, int n) {
  long d, tx, ty, tz;
  long x = cordic_1K, y = 0, z = theta;
  n = (n > CORDIC_NTAB) ? CORDIC_NTAB : n;

  for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    d = z >= 0 ? 0 : -1;
    tx = x - (((y >> k) ^ d) - d);
    ty = y + (((x >> k) ^ d) - d);
    tz = z - ((cordic_ctab[k] ^ d) - d);
    x = tx;
    y = ty;
    z = tz;
  }

  *c = x;
  *s = y;
}
```

The CORDIC table is similarly generated with bits=64.

The testing for (1) is done as below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float angle;
  long s, c;
  int failed = 0;

  cordic_ctab = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 64);
  make_cordic_ctab(64);

  for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
    angle = (i / step) * M_PI / 4;

    cordic(angle, &s, &c, 64);
    float result = s;
    float expected = sinf(angle);

    if (angle < pow(2, -27))
      result = angle;

    if (memcmp(&result, &expected, sizeof(float)) != 0) {
      failed += 1;
      printf("%e : %e\n", result, expected);
      printf("0x%x : 0x%x\n", *((unsigned int *)&result),
             *((unsigned int *)&expected));
      printf("\n");

    }
  }
  printf("failed:%d\n", failed);
}
```

The testing for (2) is done as below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float angle;
  long s, c;
  int failed = 0;
  double mul = 4611686018427387904.000000;
  double step = 1000000000.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
    angle = (i / step) * M_PI / 4;

    cordic((angle * mul), &s, &c, 64);
    float result = s / mul;
    float expected = sinf(angle);

    if (angle < pow(2, -27))
      result = angle;

    if (memcmp(&result, &expected, sizeof(float)) != 0) {
      failed += 1;
      printf("%e : %e\n", result, expected);
      printf("0x%x : 0x%x\n", *((unsigned int *)&result),
             *((unsigned int *)&expected));
      printf("\n");

    }
  }
  printf("failed:%d\n", failed);
}
```

Is there something that I don't take into account for CORDIC? Is it possible that CORDIC is completely not suitable and other methods should be considered?

Comment: Please show your code, the input values, the output of your algorithm compared to the output of the standard library functions. What do you mean with "in single precision"? What do you mean with "comparing the hexadecimal representations"? How do you get these? Depending on the capabilities of your processor, other approximations, e.g. taylor series may be faster or better.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have added the algorithm code and the way it is tested.

Comment: @Bodo The Taylor series seems to be actually much more precise (according to the tests done). However, with no FPU architecture, it will be highly inefficient.

Comment: @Daniel Do you need floating point results when you don't have an FPU? Both CORDIC and Taylor series can be implemented in fixed point (or fractional) arithmetic. IMHO it doesn't make much sense to compare floating point results of different algorithms with `memcmp`. You should check the difference compared to the actual value and define a required precision. BTW: Are you sure that `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(float)`?

Comment: @Bodo I do not agree with you. If I assume that the result of the other algorithm is correct then my result must be strictly identical. Otherwise, I am approximating to the result of the other approximation algorithm. If we were talking about computing physical distances using floating-point, for example, then yes I would need to compare the difference and see if it is correct up to some sufficient error.

Comment: @Bodo
`sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(float)`
Yes, on the architecture where I test.

Comment: @Daniel What is "correct" for a sine approximation? Calculating a floating point result of the highest precision that can be represented by the floating point format regardless of the duration or the precision of the input? Calculating a reasonable precision in a reasonable time? Calculating the best precision that can be achieved in a limited time? It depends on your needs. As you didn't write enough information about your requirements it is difficult to give an answer.

Comment: Provide a **complete** example. Your question is missing definitions of `cordic_1K`, `cordic_ctab`, and `CORDIC_NTAB`. (Code to generate them would be acceptable.) It should present **complete** code ready to compile, including `#include` statements for `<math.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, and `<string.h>`. And you should point out specifically at least one case to examine where there are errors. Also, the version 1 of the `cordic` routine is not compatible with its use in `main`, so it is not part of a complete example. You should show a separate `main` or conditionalize the existing `main`.

Comment: You can't really expect the CORDIC result to be bit-equivalent to the result from sinf(), but it should have a very small absolute difference.  You should figure out what kind of error you can tolerate in practical terms and then see if you can match that.  Note also that you are introducing some error when you quantize the angle.

Comment: @MattTimmermans why not? is CORDIC's resolution is not great enough? or I would have to make significantly more iterations for that? why then using Taylor series I can make it bit-equivalent?

Comment: 1) CORDIC will provide roughly the same accuracy over the entire range, but floating point values and the Taylor series are both more accurate very close to zero; and 2) if the ideal value is very close to the midpoint between two floats then even the smallest error can make it round in a different direction.

Comment: (1) was exactly my suspicion, which you confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a shot but as mentioned in the comments you can not expect exact bit match as math goniometrics is usually based on Chebyshev polynomials. Also you do not have defined the `cordic_1K` constant. After some search I managed to do this in **C++/VCL:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IEEE 754 single masks
const DWORD _f32_sig    =0x80000000;    // sign
const DWORD _f32_exp    =0x7F800000;    // exponent
const DWORD _f32_exp_sig=0x40000000;    // exponent sign
const DWORD _f32_exp_bia=0x3F800000;    // exponent bias
const DWORD _f32_exp_lsb=0x00800000;    // exponent LSB
const DWORD _f32_exp_pos=        23;    // exponent LSB bit position
const DWORD _f32_man    =0x007FFFFF;    // mantisa
const DWORD _f32_man_msb=0x00400000;    // mantisa MSB
const DWORD _f32_man_bits=       23;    // mantisa bits
const float _f32_lsb     =  3.4e-38;    // abs min number
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float CORDIC32_atan[_f32_man_bits+1];
void f32_sincos(float &s,float &c,float a)
    {
    int k;
    float x,y=0.0,v=1.0,d,tx,ty,ta;
    x=0.6072529350088812561694; // cordic_1K
    for (k=0;k<=_f32_man_bits;k++)
        {
        d =(a>=0.0?+1.0:-1.0);
        tx=x-d*v*y;
        ty=y+d*v*x;
        ta=a-d*CORDIC32_atan[k];
        x=tx; y=ty; a=ta; v*=0.5;
        }
    c=x; s=y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double CORDIC64_atan[_f32_man_bits+1];
void f64_sincos(float &s,float &c,double a)
    {
    int k;
    double x,y=0.0,v=1.0,d,tx,ty,ta;
    x=0.6072529350088812561694; // cordic_1K
    for (k=0;k<=_f32_man_bits;k++)
        {
        d =(a>=0.0?+1.0:-1.0);
        tx=x-d*v*y;
        ty=y+d*v*x;
        ta=a-d*CORDIC64_atan[k];
        x=tx; y=ty; a=ta; v*=0.5;
        }
    c=x; s=y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Builder: --------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    int i;
    float s0,c0,s1,c1,s2,c2,d32,d64,D32,D64,x;
    AnsiString txt="";

    // init CORDIC tables
    for (x=1.0,i=0;i<=_f32_man_bits;i++,x*=0.5)
        {
        CORDIC32_atan[i]=atan(x);
        CORDIC64_atan[i]=atan(double(x));
        }

    // 32 bit
    D32=0.0; D64=0.0;
    for (x=-0.5*M_PI;x<=+0.5*M_PI;x+=0.025)
        {
        s0=sin(x);
        c0=cos(x);
        f32_sincos(s1,c1,x); d32=fabs(s1-s0); if (D32<d32) D32=d32;
        f64_sincos(s2,c2,x); d64=fabs(s2-s0); if (D64<d64) D64=d64;
        if (d32+d64>1e-16)
            {
            txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("sin(%2.5f) == %2.5f != %2.5f != %2.5f  | %.10f %.10f\r\n",x,s0,s1,s2,d32,d64);
            f32_sincos(s0,c0,x);    // debug breakpoint
            f64_sincos(s2,c2,x);
            }
        }
    txt=AnsiString().sprintf("max err: %.10f %.10f\r\n",D32,D64)+txt;
    mm_log->Lines->Add(txt);
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can ignore the **VCL** stuff like `AnsiString` (or port it to your environment) its just for printing the results...

**The code gave me this output:**

```
max err: 0.0000002384 0.0000001192
sin(-1.54580) == -0.99969 != -0.99969 != -0.99969  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-1.52080) == -0.99875 != -0.99875 != -0.99875  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(-1.49580) == -0.99719 != -0.99719 != -0.99719  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(-1.44580) == -0.99220 != -0.99220 != -0.99220  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-1.42080) == -0.98877 != -0.98877 != -0.98877  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-1.39580) == -0.98473 != -0.98473 != -0.98473  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-1.37080) == -0.98007 != -0.98007 != -0.98007  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(-1.34580) == -0.97479 != -0.97479 != -0.97479  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-1.27080) == -0.95534 != -0.95534 != -0.95534  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(-1.24580) == -0.94765 != -0.94765 != -0.94765  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-1.22080) == -0.93937 != -0.93937 != -0.93937  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-1.19580) == -0.93051 != -0.93051 != -0.93051  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-1.17080) == -0.92106 != -0.92106 != -0.92106  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-1.14580) == -0.91104 != -0.91104 != -0.91104  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-1.12080) == -0.90045 != -0.90045 != -0.90045  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(-1.07080) == -0.87758 != -0.87758 != -0.87758  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(-1.04580) == -0.86532 != -0.86532 != -0.86532  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(-1.02080) == -0.85252 != -0.85252 != -0.85252  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-0.99580) == -0.83919 != -0.83919 != -0.83919  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(-0.97080) == -0.82534 != -0.82534 != -0.82534  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-0.94580) == -0.81096 != -0.81096 != -0.81096  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-0.92080) == -0.79608 != -0.79608 != -0.79608  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(-0.89580) == -0.78071 != -0.78071 != -0.78071  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(-0.87080) == -0.76484 != -0.76484 != -0.76484  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-0.84580) == -0.74850 != -0.74850 != -0.74850  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-0.82080) == -0.73169 != -0.73169 != -0.73169  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(-0.79580) == -0.71442 != -0.71442 != -0.71442  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-0.77080) == -0.69671 != -0.69671 != -0.69671  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-0.74580) == -0.67856 != -0.67856 != -0.67856  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(-0.72080) == -0.65998 != -0.65998 != -0.65998  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-0.69580) == -0.64100 != -0.64100 != -0.64100  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-0.67080) == -0.62161 != -0.62161 != -0.62161  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(-0.64580) == -0.60184 != -0.60184 != -0.60184  | 0.0000000596 0.0000001192
sin(-0.62080) == -0.58168 != -0.58168 != -0.58168  | 0.0000000596 0.0000001192
sin(-0.59580) == -0.56117 != -0.56117 != -0.56117  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-0.57080) == -0.54030 != -0.54030 != -0.54030  | 0.0000001788 0.0000001192
sin(-0.54580) == -0.51910 != -0.51910 != -0.51910  | 0.0000001788 0.0000001192
sin(-0.52080) == -0.49757 != -0.49757 != -0.49757  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000894
sin(-0.49580) == -0.47573 != -0.47573 != -0.47573  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000596
sin(-0.47080) == -0.45360 != -0.45360 != -0.45360  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000298
sin(-0.44580) == -0.43118 != -0.43118 != -0.43118  | 0.0000000298 0.0000000298
sin(-0.42080) == -0.40849 != -0.40849 != -0.40849  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000596
sin(-0.39580) == -0.38554 != -0.38554 != -0.38554  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(-0.37080) == -0.36236 != -0.36236 != -0.36236  | 0.0000000298 0.0000000000
sin(-0.34580) == -0.33895 != -0.33895 != -0.33895  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000298
sin(-0.32080) == -0.31532 != -0.31532 != -0.31532  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(-0.29580) == -0.29150 != -0.29150 != -0.29150  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(-0.27080) == -0.26750 != -0.26750 != -0.26750  | 0.0000000894 0.0000001192
sin(-0.24580) == -0.24333 != -0.24333 != -0.24333  | 0.0000000894 0.0000001192
sin(-0.22080) == -0.21901 != -0.21901 != -0.21901  | 0.0000000745 0.0000000894
sin(-0.19580) == -0.19455 != -0.19455 != -0.19455  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000596
sin(-0.17080) == -0.16997 != -0.16997 != -0.16997  | 0.0000001043 0.0000000894
sin(-0.14580) == -0.14528 != -0.14528 != -0.14528  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000894
sin(-0.12080) == -0.12050 != -0.12050 != -0.12050  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000671
sin(-0.09580) == -0.09565 != -0.09565 != -0.09565  | 0.0000000522 0.0000000522
sin(-0.07080) == -0.07074 != -0.07074 != -0.07074  | 0.0000000075 0.0000000224
sin(-0.04580) == -0.04578 != -0.04578 != -0.04578  | 0.0000000447 0.0000000335
sin(-0.02080) == -0.02080 != -0.02080 != -0.02080  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000577
sin(0.00420) == 0.00420 != 0.00420 != 0.00420  | 0.0000000545 0.0000000549
sin(0.02920) == 0.02920 != 0.02920 != 0.02920  | 0.0000000447 0.0000000410
sin(0.05420) == 0.05418 != 0.05418 != 0.05418  | 0.0000000149 0.0000000186
sin(0.07920) == 0.07912 != 0.07912 != 0.07912  | 0.0000000224 0.0000000373
sin(0.10420) == 0.10401 != 0.10401 != 0.10401  | 0.0000000820 0.0000000745
sin(0.12920) == 0.12884 != 0.12884 != 0.12884  | 0.0000001043 0.0000000894
sin(0.15420) == 0.15359 != 0.15359 != 0.15359  | 0.0000001043 0.0000001043
sin(0.17920) == 0.17825 != 0.17825 != 0.17825  | 0.0000000447 0.0000000745
sin(0.20420) == 0.20279 != 0.20279 != 0.20279  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000745
sin(0.22920) == 0.22720 != 0.22720 != 0.22720  | 0.0000001043 0.0000001043
sin(0.25420) == 0.25147 != 0.25147 != 0.25147  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000894
sin(0.27920) == 0.27559 != 0.27559 != 0.27559  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(0.30420) == 0.29953 != 0.29953 != 0.29953  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000298
sin(0.32920) == 0.32329 != 0.32329 != 0.32329  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(0.35420) == 0.34684 != 0.34684 != 0.34684  | 0.0000000298 0.0000000298
sin(0.37920) == 0.37018 != 0.37018 != 0.37018  | 0.0000000298 0.0000000298
sin(0.40420) == 0.39329 != 0.39329 != 0.39329  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(0.42920) == 0.41615 != 0.41615 != 0.41615  | 0.0000000894 0.0000000894
sin(0.45420) == 0.43875 != 0.43875 != 0.43875  | 0.0000000298 0.0000000000
sin(0.47920) == 0.46107 != 0.46107 != 0.46107  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000298
sin(0.50420) == 0.48311 != 0.48311 != 0.48311  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(0.52920) == 0.50485 != 0.50485 != 0.50485  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(0.55420) == 0.52627 != 0.52627 != 0.52627  | 0.0000002384 0.0000001192
sin(0.57920) == 0.54736 != 0.54736 != 0.54736  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(0.60420) == 0.56811 != 0.56811 != 0.56811  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(0.62920) == 0.58850 != 0.58850 != 0.58850  | 0.0000000596 0.0000001192
sin(0.65420) == 0.60853 != 0.60853 != 0.60853  | 0.0000001192 0.0000001192
sin(0.67920) == 0.62817 != 0.62817 != 0.62817  | 0.0000000596 0.0000001192
sin(0.70420) == 0.64743 != 0.64743 != 0.64743  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(0.72920) == 0.66628 != 0.66628 != 0.66628  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(0.75420) == 0.68471 != 0.68471 != 0.68471  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(0.77920) == 0.70271 != 0.70271 != 0.70271  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(0.82920) == 0.73739 != 0.73739 != 0.73739  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(0.85420) == 0.75405 != 0.75405 != 0.75405  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(0.87920) == 0.77023 != 0.77023 != 0.77023  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(0.90420) == 0.78593 != 0.78593 != 0.78593  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(0.92920) == 0.80114 != 0.80114 != 0.80114  | 0.0000000596 0.0000001192
sin(0.95420) == 0.81585 != 0.81585 != 0.81585  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(0.97920) == 0.83005 != 0.83005 != 0.83005  | 0.0000000000 0.0000000596
sin(1.00420) == 0.84373 != 0.84373 != 0.84373  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000000
sin(1.02920) == 0.85689 != 0.85689 != 0.85689  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.05420) == 0.86951 != 0.86951 != 0.86951  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(1.12920) == 0.90407 != 0.90407 != 0.90407  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.15420) == 0.91447 != 0.91447 != 0.91447  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(1.17920) == 0.92430 != 0.92430 != 0.92430  | 0.0000001788 0.0000000596
sin(1.20420) == 0.93355 != 0.93355 != 0.93355  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.25420) == 0.95030 != 0.95030 != 0.95030  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(1.27920) == 0.95779 != 0.95779 != 0.95779  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000596
sin(1.30420) == 0.96467 != 0.96467 != 0.96467  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.35420) == 0.97664 != 0.97664 != 0.97663  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000596
sin(1.45420) == 0.99321 != 0.99321 != 0.99321  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.47920) == 0.99581 != 0.99581 != 0.99581  | 0.0000001192 0.0000000000
sin(1.50420) == 0.99778 != 0.99778 != 0.99778  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.52920) == 0.99914 != 0.99914 != 0.99914  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
sin(1.55420) == 0.99986 != 0.99986 != 0.99986  | 0.0000000596 0.0000000000
```

As you can see the 64 bit tables produce much better match to math `sin` the error is up to `4 ulp` (2^-24) for 32 bit and `2 ulp` (2^-24) for 64 bit tables. As the mantissa of 32 bit float is `23+1` bits the result corresponds to 2 least significant bits of mantissa so its last hexadecimal digit is not matching ...

PS the `atan` table is:

```cpp
CORDIC64_atan[24]={ 0.785398163397448, 0.463647609000806, 0.244978663126864, 0.124354994546761, 0.0624188099959574, 0.0312398334302683, 0.0156237286204768, 0.00781234106010111, 0.00390623013196697, 0.00195312251647882, 0.00097656218955932, 0.000488281211194898, 0.000244140620149362, 0.00012207031189367, 6.10351561742088E-05, 3.05175781155261E-05, 1.52587890613158E-05, 7.62939453110197E-06, 3.8146972656065E-06, 1.90734863281019E-06, 9.53674316405961E-07, 4.76837158203089E-07, 2.38418579101558E-07, 1.19209289550781E-07 };
```

Comment: Thank you! So it seems that a lot more iterations are required in order to match math's `sin` ?

Comment: @Daniel no, Each iteration is representing one bit of mantissa so if you do more iteration than mantissa bits the result is not affected due to rounding. The difference is caused mainly due to different way of computing. You know math sin cos are rounded too ...

Comment: right. I meant increasing iterations with computation precision. Just for completing my understanding: If I could compute the CORDIC in Xbits, where X is the number of possible exponents in the relevant range times 23 bits of the significand, then I could obtain the correct result for a float?

Comment: IIRC math `sin` and `cos` has `+/-1 ulp` error ... so up to `2 ulp` error difference to CORDIC might be just opposite rounding by `1 ulp` of both variants ... so the 64 bit variant might have the same accuracy as the `sin` and `cos` you are comparing to ...

Comment: @Spektre: Re “IIRC math `sin` and `cos` has +/-1 ulp error”: The accuracy of math library routines is implementation-dependent. Nobody has implemented all of the math library routines with known-bounded run-time, although I think CRlibm covered sine and cosine. Commercial implementations may be 3-4 ULP, for example. Using the `double` `sin` as a reference for single-precision `sinf` would likely give a very nearly ½ ULP value (using the single-precision ULP).